# Core data query value "is not nil" is not returning object with value equal 0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to return objects (Measure) where property `rawValue` is not nil. My predicate is:

```
myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "rawValue != %@", "nil")
```

**And my request**

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Measure")

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        let fetchResults = try managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Measure]
        if fetchResults!.count > 0{
            measuresFetched = fetchResults!
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

The problem is that my query is not returning objects with `rawValue` = 0. And for me 0 is not nil.

**My objects looks like below**

```
class Measure: NSManagedObject{

    @NSManaged var rawValue: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate

    class func createInManagedObjectContext(moc: NSManagedObjectContext,rawValue: Double?, date: NSDate) -> Measure {
        let newItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Measure", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! Measure
        newItem.rawValue = rawValue
        newItem.date = date
        return newItem
    }

}
```

How can I return all objects where rawValue is not nil ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try predicate like this

```
myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "rawValue != nil")
```

Comment: I did not try it because I though it was exactly the same between `myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "rawValue != nil")` and `myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "rawValue != %@", "nil")` ... I need to understand what is the difference between them

Comment: as per your implementation 
`myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "rawValue != 'nil' ")`

Comment: so it is different then my proposed predicates